# Rcpp Code chrashes after updating Rcpp from 1.0.6 to 1.0.7

Tags: rcpp

I'm using a self-written model in Rcpp which works fine when using Rcpp 1.0.6 or 1.0.5. But after updating to Rcpp 1.0.7 the model run crashes right after executing the R function to start the model. (However, compilation with sourceCpp() works without any error or warning.)

The code in Rcpp is organized as follows: there are several functions written in different c++-files and these functions are loaded with header files into my runModel.cpp file that defines my function that is exported to R to run the code.

This function is used like this runModel(DateVector SimPeriod, List ModelInput, NumericVector Settings). Maybe it is worth noting that functions in different c++-files are using the same variables and changing them sometimes, so I had to write also something like initModel.cpp and a correspondent header file which is imported in almost every c++ files.

I was already looking in the https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/news.html to relate the made changes in 1.0.7 to my issue. But unfortunately, I have no idea what might be the reason for the crash. I'm appreciating every comment on this.

I'm sorry that I cannot give a reproducible example but the model code is too complex to create one (especially because I do not know where the error is hidden.)

Comment: C++ can be hairy.  Make sure _everything_ related to the compilation unit (_i.e._ other packages dependng on Rcpp) is rebuilt under 1.0.7.  Once that is cleared it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The update of all installed packages and deleting all .o-files and creating a completely new compilation solved the problem!